# Most efficient way to merge multiple rows of a pandas dataframe in to one row, adding new columns to the row, based on values in the initial rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe made up of demographic attributes and survey questions and answers. The questions are multiple choice and multi-select. Each row in the initial dataframe indicates a single answer of a single question. So there are multiple rows for each respondent and for each question. The initial dataframe looks like this:

```
user_id  question    answer   age  gender
1        question_1  answer3  34   male
1        question_1  answer5  34   male
1        question_2  answer1  34   male
1        question_2  answer4  34   male
2        question_1  answer1  22   female
2        question_1  answer3  22   female
```

I want to change the dataframe, so that each row represents all of the answers for a single respondent. In the new dataframe there would only be one row for each respondent and a column for each question/answer combination. The question/answer column value would contain a 1 if the respondent answered the question with the corresponding answer. The new dataframe should look something like this:

```
user_id  age  gender  q1_ans1  q1_ans3 q1_ans5 q2_ans1 q2_ans4
1        34   male    0        1       1       1       1
2        22   female  1        1       0       0       0
```

I have tried to achieve this by creating a new dataframe, going through each row using itertuples(), checking if the new dataframe contains the row for the relevant respondent, if it doesn't then creating a new row in the new dataframe with a new column, named as a combination of the question and answer fields in the current row, with 1 as the value, and if it does then finding the row for the respondent and adding a new column, naming it as a combination of the question and answer from the current row and setting the value to 1.

The problem is that this is super slow. Is there a more efficient way of achieving this using dataframes? And if not, then is there another solution? Any help will be much appreciated. The code is below:

```
def process_raw_df(self):
    raw_df = self.dc.get_data_frame()
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user_id', 'occupation_label', 
                                   'relationship_label', 'age', 
                                   'income_tier', 'income',
                                   'has_children', 'country', 'city'])
    new_df.set_index('user_id')

    for row in raw_df.itertuples():
        new_column_name = str(row[2]) + str(row[3])
        if new_df.loc[new_df['user_id'] == row[0]]['user_id'].count() 
         == 0:
            new_row = [[row[1], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], 
                       row[9], row[10], row[11], 1]]
            new_row_df = pd.DataFrame(new_row, columns=['user_id', 
                  'occupation_label', 'relationship_label', 'age',
                  'income_tier', 'income', 'has_children', 'country', 
                  'city', new_column_name])
            new_df.append(new_row_df)
        else:
            new_df.loc[new_df['user_id'] == row[1], new_column_name] = 
            1
    return new_df
```

Comment: Can you past a sample of your initial dataframe and the solution dataframe for that sample?

Comment: Done. Thanks for your response.

Comment: How many questions are there in total? How many options do each question have?

Answer (score 0):

Alright , this is highly un-optimized code to do a simple thing. 
You need the apply functionality of pandas.

Try apply and pivot

The new column should be a flag if answer exists:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x : return user_flagger(x[2])
df.pivot(index='userid', columns='question', values='newcolumn')
```

Then flag all the answers that are none to 0 ,etc. 
I will leave the exact coding part of it as an exercise to you. :)

Edit: since the column name matters to you, have an extra column which concatenates column question and column answer. After that pivot on the concatenated column name and the value obtained from the flagger function. Spend a couple of minutes reading about pivot in pandas and I am sure the answer will become clear. If you are still unable to, I will post a working code here.

Code:

```
df['pivot_column']=df['question'].str.replace('question_','q')+'_'+df['answer'].str.replace('answer','ans')

df['flag']=1
df2 = df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='pivot_column', values='flag')
```

This solution has a small problem - it does not take gender and age , see if this code performs faster than the group by mentioned below. If it does , you can get back the age and gender by doing a join.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to attempt this approach. With the top line, would I have to do this for each new column (each question/answer combination) And I would pass the question and answer columns to the user_flagger function? Then the user_flagger function would return 1 if the question and answer apply to the new column name I'm creating and 0 if not? And if I'm creating the new columns first, why would I then do a pivot on the question column?

Comment: Quite the opposite, first create a new column that is Boolean ( if the question has answer, give it 1 else 0) , use the pivot post that like mentioned in the code.

Comment: I've had a go at this and this line doesn't seem to work: raw_df['pivot_column'] = raw_df['survey_question'] + '_' + raw_df['answer'] The values for the question and answer columns are actually bytearrays rather than strings, so the columns are just coming out as numbers. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Can you paste an example of a value in this column

Comment: example of survey_question value: "How often do you exercise?" (as bytearray thanks to mysql connector). Example of answer value: "I don't exercise at all" (also as bytearray). I'm struggling with this one tbh

Comment: raw_df = self.dc.get_data_frame()
        raw_df['pivot_column'] = raw_df.apply(self.get_col_name, axis=1)
        raw_df['flag'] = 1
        df2 = raw_df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='pivot_column', values='flag')

Comment: It works up until the pivot, where I get an error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. So it can't pivot using an index that has multiple entries? How can I get around that when of course there will be multiple entries of a user_id in this column?

Comment: here is the get_col_name function I pass to apply. This works now:     def get_col_name(self, x):
        return str(x[1]) + '_' + str(x[2])

Comment: Does your dataset have multiple records for a user and a particular question, that could be the only reason I can think of. I cannot reproduce the error you have mentioned.

Comment: Exactly, it does. The questions are multiple choice and multi-select, so each user and each question can be on multiple rows when a user selects more than one answer for a particular question.

Comment: Is there a way of handling this using this solution? Thanks for your time.